# How to pass data to a controller via delegate callback having a tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

[Please have a look at the screenshot of my project for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxup.png)
I have browsed a lot in stack overflow and other sites regarding writing custom delegates. But in my case the delegate is not getting called. As can be seen in the screenshot, the initial view controller has a button on click of which the tab bar gets called. From the first Tab bar screen, suppose I want to pass the data back to the initial view controller, how do I do? I can even use NSUserDefaults but I want to code the right way. So I came to know that delegates are best way to pass data back from one controller to the previous controller. But since I am using tab bars in between, the delegate is not getting called.. Kindly help,

Following is the code,
I want data to be passed from first tab to the initial controller.

TabScreenController.h:

```
@protocol TabScreenControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)someFunction:(NSString*)someValue;
@end

@interface TabScreenController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <TabScreenControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

InitialViewController.h:

```
@interface InitialViewController : UIViewController<TabScreenControllerDelegate>
```

InitialViewController.m:

```
TabScreenController* controller = [[TabScreenController alloc]init];
[controller setDelegate:self];


//The delegate is not getting called
-(void)someFunction:(NSString *)someValue{
    NSLog(@"%@", someValue);
}
```

The delegate is not getting called perhaps the TabScreenController in InitialViewController.m is a different instance than the one that gets created on clicking the tab.

Please help me regarding this.. How do I handle such scenarios. Let me know if I have not made myself clear..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are not setting the delegate the **existing** `TabScreenController` but instantiating a new `TabScreenController` and setting the delegate.  When using `TabBarController` all the `childViewControllers` are already instantiated.
In your case you need to look for `TabScreenController` and then set its delegate.

```
NSArray* tabChildViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;


for (UIViewController * childVC in tabChildViewControllers) {

     if ([childVC isKindOfClass:[TabScreenController class]]) {
         // set your the delegate

     }
 }
```